# Returning a table from a function with parameters in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

As far as I know, we can return a table as a result of a db function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction(@Value varchar(100))
RETURNS table
AS RETURN (select * from MyTable where ColumnName = '@Value')
```

in this example we can make the column name as a parameter for the function. My question is, can we write the column name and table name as a parameter for the function? hence we can write a more generic function something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyGenericSearchFunction(@TableName varchar(100), @ColumnName varchar(100), @Value varchar(100))
RETURNS table
AS RETURN (select * from @TableName where @ColumnName = '@Value')
```

Comment: No, you cannot parameterize table or column names in a static query. And you cannot use dynamic SQL in a function.

Comment: If you have multiple tables that have the same structure (which would also be a requirement given your indicated query, since the structure of a function's return type must also be fixed), it's usually an indication that the tables should be merged and an additional column be introduced to hold the information that's currently being held in those table's *name*.

Comment: No. Use a stored procedure for this (or fix the design).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.

This would then be a dynamic query.
For dynamic queries in SQL Server, one has to use exec() or sp_executesql() functions, which are not allowed in functions.